# how to remove all characters from string and leave numbers only in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

i have couple columns in data frame that contains numeric values and string
and i want to remove all characters and leave only numbers

```
Admit_DX_Description            Primary_DX_Description
510.9 - EMPYEMA W/O FISTULA     510.9 - EMPYEMA W/O FISTULA
681.10 - CELLULITIS, TOE NOS    681.10 - CELLULITIS, TOE NOS
780.2 - SYNCOPE AND COLLAPSE    427.89 - CARDIAC DYSRHYTHMIAS NEC
729.5 - PAIN IN LIMB            998.30 - DISRUPTION OF WOUND, UNSPEC
```

to

```
Admit_DX_Description            Primary_DX_Description
510.9                             510.9 
681.10                            681.10 
780.2                             427.89 
729.5                             998.30
```

code:

```
  for col in strip_col:
       # # Encoding only categorical variables
       if df[col].dtypes =='object':
           df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: x.rstrip(r'[a-zA-Z]'))

print df.head()
```

error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: x.rstrip(r'[a-zA-Z]'))
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2175, in map
    new_values = map_f(values, arg)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1217, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:63307)

```
df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: x.rstrip(r'[a-zA-Z]'))
```

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example:

I chose `re` module to extract float numbers only.

```
import re
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['Hello 199.9', '19.99 Hello'], 'B': ['700.52 Test', 'Test 7.7']})

df
             A            B
0  Hello 199.9  700.52 Test
1  19.99 Hello     Test 7.7

for col in df:
    df[col] = [''.join(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", item)) for item in df[col]]

       A       B
0  199.9  700.52
1  19.99     7.7
```

If you have integer numbers also, change `re pattern` to this: `\d*\.?\d+`.

***EDITED***

For `TypeError` I'd recommend to use `try`. In this example I created a list `errs`. This list will be used in `except TypeError`. You can `print (errs)` to see those values.

Check `df` too.

```
...
...
errs = []
for col in df:
    try:
        df[col] = [''.join(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", item)) for item in df[col]]
    except TypeError:
        errs.extend([item for item in df[col]])
```

Comment: hey it is a great answer but i am getting this error  **TypeError: expected string or buffer** but i figured out that some strings have values similar to this  "250.82 - DIABETES,.TYPE II" do you have any idea for i can handle this

Comment: I run this new dataframe: `df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['250.82 - DIABETES,.TYPE II', '19.99 Hello'], 'B': ['700.52 Test', 'Test 7.7']})` and I don't get any `TypeError`. Maybe is another string different from ***250.82 - DIABETES,.TYPE II***.

Comment: i dont know but it could be something like that  **V22.0 - SUPERVIS NORMAL 1ST PREG**

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [df.applymap](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) and apply it over the columns from which you want to remove the text.
[edited]
Alternatively:

```
import pandas as pd 
test = [{'c1':10, 'c2':100}, {'c1':11,'c2':110}, {'c1':12,'c2':120}] 
fun = lambda x: x+10 
df = pd.DataFrame(test) 
df['c1'] = df['c1'].apply(fun) 
print df
```

Comment: i tried it but i getting this error  **AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'**